# Highlight a particular word in a paragraph which is entered in a Textbox

Tags: angularjs

I am a complete beginner in AngularJS(1.x). I have taken this code from plnkr but here i have done some modification ie i removed the hardcoded input  and click function https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/wtxZme

wanted below scenario in the code provided below

enter some text in a textbox, and  need to highlight the entered text(in yellow color) in the paragraph.if two time same word is present it should reflect at two places,and without using Regex.

Can anyone provide any ideas on how to proceed?

aap.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);



app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.words ='';



$scope.text = "blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah";



$scope.words = '';



});



  app.filter('highlightWord', function() {

  return function(text, words) {

  if(words) {

    var pattern = new RegExp(words);

    return text.replace(pattern, '<span class="highlighted">' + words 
     + '</span>');

  }

  else {

    return text;

  }

   };
```

index.html

```
    <html ng-app="plunker">
    <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />

<title>AngularJS Plunker</title>

<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

<script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js" data-semver="1.0.7"></script>

  <script src="app.js"></script>

  </head>



 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

   enter word:

<input type=text ng-model="words"><br>

Selected:

<div style="border: red thin solid; width: 100px; padding: 10px;" ng-
  bind-html-unsafe="text | highlightWord : words"></div>

</div>

Selected Word: {{words}}
```

css
     /* Put your css in here */

```
 .highlighted {
 background-color: yellow; 
  }
```

Comment: " which already has that word" what does this mean . Provide some example with proper discription

Comment: Please create [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example

Comment: what modification you did in the code mention that as well

Comment: i think you don't have Css at your end

Comment: @Viplock i  have added css code also. whatever the code i have provided ,there i want to implement it without using regexp..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can do that by updating you method by this 
I mean you can split the text by the word you want to replace and join the word by the updated value

```
app.filter('highlightWord', function() {

  return function(text, words) {

  if(words) {

  return text.split(words).join('<span class="highlighted">' + words + '</span>')

  }

  else {

    return text;

  }

   };
```

Check this out https://plnkr.co/edit/wtxZme?p=info